# If $v$, $w$, and $v + w$ are nonzero, and $v$ and $v + w$ parallel, then $v$ and $w$ are parallel.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am quite sure this is true but I do not know where to start.

> If $v$, $w$, and $v + w$ are nonzero, and $v$ and $v + w$ parallel, then $v$ and $w$ are parallel.

Comment: As a hint: how can you check mathematically whether two vectors are "parallel"?

Comment: if they are scalar multiples of each other?

Comment: ohh i think i got it

Comment: Consider what it *means* for two vectors to be parallel.  $a$ and $b$ are parallel iff _______ (*some equality involving $a$ and $b$, do you remember what it was?*)  Now... suppose that $v$ and $v+w$ are parallel, and do some algebraic manipulations.  What do you learn as a result?

Comment: If you get it you can now answer your own question.

Comment: done, i'm fairly sure it is correct

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  Being parallel means one is a scalar multiple of the other.  Start with $v=k(v+w)$ and work from there

Comment: yup, thank you, just figured it out

Answer (score 2):

Since we know v and v+w are parallel, we have

> v = a(v+w)
>
> v = av + aw
>
> v - av = aw
>
> (1-a)v = aw

Since a is a scalar, subtracting it from 1 still results in a scalar. From this, we can see that v  and w are scalar multiples of each other and are therefore parallel.

Comment: You should make mention why certain elements aren't zero, but otherwise it is correct.  Remember that we don't consider the zero vector to be parallel to anything.